# Using SearchCursor & InsertCursor to populate up fields from a Polyline Featureclass

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I'm having some problems inputting the [OID] and [FEA_KEY] fields into a point featureclass I've created from extracting the [lastPoint property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001s000000) from a line featureclass.

Error is:

```
for item in sCurs:
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
```

...since I can see that I created the required fields in the outFc..I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
## turn ss line feature vertices into points - try using only endpoints. Include the
## [OID] and [FEA_KEY] for each vertice in the outFc

def VerticesToPoints(inFc, outFc):
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    try:
        # let esri do it (advanced license)
        arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(inFc, outFc, "ALL")
        return outFc
    except:
        pass
    # no advanced license
    sr = arcpy.Describe(inFc).spatialReference
    outPath, outName = os.path.split(outFc)
    start = time.clock()
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outPath,
                                        outName,
                                        "POINT",
                                        spatial_reference=sr)
    arcpy.AddField_management(outFc, "OID", "LONG")
    arcpy.AddField_management(outFc, "FEA_KEY", "LONG")
    end = time.clock()
    sds.writeLog(logFile, "Create Feature Class {}".format(outFc))
## USE SHAPE@ which would give you a polyline geometry object. There is a lastPoint property on that object.
    i = 0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", "OID", "FEA_KEY"]) as sCurs:
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFc,["OID@", "SHAPE@", "OID", "FEA_KEY"]) as iCurs:
            for item in sCurs:
                iCurs.insertRow([item[0], (item[1].lastPoint.X, item[1].lastPoint.Y), item[2], item[3]])
                # for testing purposes, just run through 12 of these
                i += 1
                if i >= 12:
                    break
    return outFc
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! by printing all the fields in the feature class  using arcpy.ListFields() turns out FEA_KEY is an alias - not a full name. Noting this here in case anyone else gets stumped.